# Помогите с библиотекой telebot на phyton

Tags: python, telebot, visual-studio-code

Библиотеку я установил в cmd используя команду,
но в vs code после импортирования библиотеки нет emmit
а бот просто не работает
возможно библиотека не правильно установилось или вовсе не установилась

Помогите пожалуйста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы пробовали запустить файл? `python telebot.py` и причем тут emmit?

Comment: Вставляйте пожалуйста код/ошибки текстом.

Comment: `import telebot` внутри файла telebot.py будет пытаться бесконечно импортировать сам себя. Переименуйте файл.